# How to configure a custom domain name for web app running on port 80 in non-classic azure virtual machine

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, domain-name

I created a NodeJs web on non-classic virtual machine in Azure cloud. Then I started the app on port 80 as follows:

`sudo NODE_ENV=production PORT=80 node server/app.js`

The app started successfully. I also enabled port 80 using NSG.

I can access the app using IP address.

Now I purchased a domain name in names.co.uk and linked the IP address to record A(on registrar site). The same way as I was doing for the AWS site which is currently working.

But I could not access the app using custom domain name but app can be accessed directly using IP address.

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way  I did is absolutely correct. The only problem was that it took some time to get the changes reflected.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to follow this guide on official site [Create a Fully Qualified Domain Name in the Azure portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-create-fqdn-on-portal/), configure with the CName on your DNS service leveraging the Domain. It works fine on my side.

Besides, if you don't see the "public ip address" as the capture shows on the guide, you can find the ip address in this steps:
[image]

As if you don't have a static ip address, the public ip may change when your VM start each time.